# Adding text to uiwebview using javascript function at specific location in ios

Tags: ios, uiwebview

> Blockquote

in my app I want to add text in specific location I tried to change the top and left property of text in js code but still it injecting text at 0,0.

Thanks in advance

objective-c code

```
NSString *stringToAddToCanvas=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"addText('%@')",m_textToAdd];
[canvas stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:stringToAddToCanvas];
```

js code

```
function addText(text)

{    canvas.isDrawingMode = false;
     var objectVar = new fabric.Text(text, {
                                fontFamily: 'Arial',
                                fontSize: 90,
                                left: 0,
                                top: 0,
                                textAlign: "center",
                                fontWeight: 'bold',
                                borderColor :drawingColor,
                                fill:fillColor
                                });


canvas.add(objectVar);
objectsArray.push(objectVar);
objectsTimeDurationArray.push(0);
}
```

Comment: show some code of what you have tried first

Comment: @iamIcarus code added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the solution it is very strange but to reflect changes in my .js file I need to delete my app from device then install it, all the changes made in .js file working perfectly